How can i iterate through this list and return a text if threshold not met?
scores = [0.9,0.8,0.3,0.4]
new=[]
for sc in scores:
    if sc < 0.8:
        pass
    else:
        new.append(sc)

print(new)

however i want to also include a response IF none of the scores are >0.8 then print "none of the scores in list had a score that met threshold"
how can i do this in an efficient manner?

At the end, check if new is empty and print the message.

BTW, there's no need for the if...: pass block. Just invert the test: if sc >= 0.8: new.append(sc). You can also do the whole thing as a list comprehension: new = [sc for sc in scores if sc >= 0.8]

If do not add any numbers to your new array, it's length will remain 0.

You can simply check if the list is empty at the end, like:
scores = [0.9,0.8,0.3,0.4]
new=[]
for sc in scores:
    if sc < 0.8:
        pass
    else:
        new.append(sc)

if new:
    print(new)
else:
    print("none of the scores in list had a score that met threshold")

In python, if a list is empty, its value is false when type casted as a bool. If you want to be more explicit, you could say: if len(new) > 0

If you wanted to tighten up the code a bit, you can use list comprehension to create the list of scores meeting the criteria (new), and print the result.
Essentially, doing the entire job on two lines, while maintaining moderate readability.
For example:
new = [i for i in scores if i >= 0.8]
print(new if new else 'No scores.')

Output:
[0.9, 0.8]

Raising the criteria (e.g. >= 1) will print No scores. to the terminal.

Aside, just for kicks (and completeness) you can use the filter function, which might provide an efficiency gain for large lists; by enabling generator usage. But really, that’s out of the depth here, and doesn’t apply to this specific use case.
list(filter(lambda x: x >= 0.8, scores))


filter won't be any more efficient. It forces you to call a user-defined function to make the comparison.

@chepner - Fair point.  Updated to complete my original thought regarding opening the way for generators.

You can print with logical OR:
print(new or "none of the scores in list had a score that met threshold")

